# How to make static variable null when navigate away from a page?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010, static

I have 2 page: 1. Add/Edit page 2. List page. In the List page, I have a grid view. On editing a row from grid view, I set a static variable for the ID with the datakey value and redirects to the Add/Edit page and pre-populate it with the edit row data. I am using same page to add and edit. Here is my problem, after I click edit from the List page, am redirected to the Add/Edit page with edit data pre-populated. But when I navigate away from this page and revisits after few other business, I get the page pre-populated since am checking against the static variable, which I don't want to happen. I want to make the static variable to null once I navigate away from the Add/Edit page. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you considered using the [Session object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead of a static variable?

Comment: am using sharepoint 2010 visual webparts. I think it doesn't allow session variables.

Comment: Maybe this can help http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointgeneralprevious/thread/12542f5d-a4a3-4662-b690-8d73bbc642f1